# Trouble getting React countdown timer to stop

Tags: reactjs, timer

I'm new to React, but I found and modified a countdown timer to work for my purposes. However, I can't figure out how to get the timer to stop.  I just want the output to read "0:00" when it finishes.

So I'm not including the beginning of my component that sets the amount of time, but here's the rest:

```
  const timeBetween = targetTime - currentTime;
  const seconds = Math.floor((timeBetween / 1000) % 60);
  const minutes = Math.floor((timeBetween / 1000 / 60) % 60);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCurrentTime(Date.now());
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="content2">
        <p style={{ color: "white" }}>We start in:</p>
        <p style={{ color: "white" }}>
          <span>{`${minutes}:${seconds < 10 ? "0" : ""}${seconds}`}</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, you just need to add a check condition before you `setCurrentTime`

Just check if targetTime has already surpassed current time and remove the interval if the time has passed.

```
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  if (targetTime > new Date()) {
    setCurrentTime(Date.now());
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 1000);
```

Here is a working [stakblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zshynh)

Comment: thanks. I had tried an IF statement, but it didn't work.  When I changed my useEffect code to reflect yours, the timer does not count down.  But I took your example and made it a different component, and it worked.  So obviously I have something in my code that's preventing your solution from counting down.  I'll have to keep digging.